# Tablet and phone text link

Tags: html, css, mobile, hyperlink, phone-number

My website HTML contains a phone number as a text. So, the iPad tablet interprets that as a phone - and turns it into an underline
blue link.

Is it possible to format phone number to a different style?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off telephone number detection by adding the following to your page:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Source: [Apple URL Scheme Reference : Phone Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)

Be sure to consider other devices and operating systems as well. For instance, to disable this on the BlackBerry, the following is needed:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-rim-auto-match" content="none">
```

Source: [BlackBerry: Link Behavior](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_link_behaviour_438487_11.jsp)